# Calculating a Streak from a column in Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, if-statement

I have a `df` that has a `Basket` column of hits `H` and misses `H`.  I am calculating a streak from this column. My `df` looks like this,

```
    vs   game quarter   Basket      
0   ORL    1    1           H
1   ORL    1    1           M
2   ORL    1    1           M
3   ORL    1    1           H
4   ORL    1    1           H
5   ORL    1    1           M
6   ORL    1    1           M
7   ORL    1    1           M
8   ORL    1    1           M
9   ORL    1    2           H
10  ORL    1    2           H
11  ORL    1    2           H
12  ORL    1    2           M
```

This is how, I have my function,

```
count = 0
def count_hit(x):
    global count
    if x == 'H':
        count += 1     
    else:
        count = 0
    return count
```

After this, I created a variable `Streak` with above function as function does I get the

```
Streak = df['Basket'].apply(count_hit)
print(Streak)
>> 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

However, I need my `Streak` like this,

```
1 0 2 0 0 0 3
```

Here, for example, first Streak `1` is a `H` followed by miss `M` (Indexed 1 through 1 and there is a 0 after because of miss in 2nd index). Second Streak is `2` that goes from index 3 through 5.

How should I tweak my function here to calculate like that. I want to go to the next `M` miss as soon as `H` hit ends to calculate a streak.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Currently you want the following pairings: `(('H',1), ('M',0), ('M',2), ('H',0), ('H',0), ('M',0), ('M',3), ('M',?), ('M',?), ...)`. Its a little difficult to see how you get from the column you have to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
In [5233]: streak, count = [], 0

In [5234]: for x in df.Basket:
      ...:     if x == 'H':
      ...:         count += 1
      ...:     elif x == 'M':
      ...:         streak.append(count)
      ...:         count = 0

In [5235]: streak
Out[5235]: [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```